# in test server javascript in not loading IIS

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am deploying the Asp.net application on two different server test servers and a production server. in the production server, everything is fine but in the test server, JavaScript is not loading in chrome while in edge it's working fine. I have removed the content security policy header from the middleware but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

This happens many times because when loading the script you need to update a version (otherwise it doesn't update the loading of the script), try adding like this:

```
<script src="myscripts.js@DataTime.Now"></script>
```

That way it will reload the script for you on every restart

Comment: not solved after refreshing same error